# Grouping numbers so they approximate their total divided by two

Tags: algorithms

Given an array of numbers, I would like to find an algorithm which divides them into two groups, such that the sum of the numbers in each group is as close as possible to half of the sum of all numbers, meaning I am looking for two groups whose sums are as similar as possible to each other.

As an example, given the array `[120, 100, 33, 57]`, the goal would be

```
(120 + 100 + 33 + 57) / 2 = 155
```

The subgroups whose sums best approximate this number are `[120, 33]` and `[100, 57]`, as they result in a sum of `153` and `157`, respectively, for a distance of `2` from the goal. If we were to go with e.g. `[120, 57]` and `[100, 33]`, their distance of `22` from the goal would be quite a bit bigger and thus less ideal.

One more example:

```
array = [44, 18, 71, 109, 29]
goal = 135.5
subgroups = [[109, 29], [44, 18, 71]]
distance = 2.5
```

Is there a way to do this, besides brute forcing it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution